# Using find to list all files under certain directory

Tags: bash, command-line, find, ls

I'm trying to use a single line command that will find every directory (or sub-directory) named `bin` and will then print a list of all the files under it, but will not also list the directory names under them.

I've tried a couple different things to accomplish this, but so far none have worked:

1. `find ~ -type d -name "bin" -exec ls '{}' ';' | grep -v /`

I tested this and it will list the files, but it also list directories under whatever bin is there. So if I have a `bin` sub-directory under a `bin` directory that looks like this:

```
~/home/
   ~/home/bin
      file1.txt
      ~/home/bin/bin
         file2.txt
```

The output looks something like this:

```
bin
file1.txt
file2.txt
```

2. `find ~ -type d -name "bin" -exec ls -f '{}' ';'`

I read that doing `ls -f` will list only files, but this unfortunately also lists the directories `bin`, `..` and `.`

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `-path`, you could try:

```
find ~ -path '*/bin/*' -type f
```

This won't list `bin` itself, so to get both:

```
find ~ \( -path '*/bin/*' -type f \) -o \( -name bin -type d \)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with nested `find` calls:

```
$ find ~ -type d -name bin -exec find '{}' -type f ';'
```

Since I'm replacing an `ls` call, perhaps you did not want more than one level of listing in the second `find` call. In that case, add `-maxdepth 1` after `-type f` above.