# Search files for a string and if found check if a file with paired name exists in the same directory

Tags: grep, find, ls

I have many different files with the same ending `.ft1` that may or may not contain one specific word `special`. For the files that contain this word, I want to check whether another file with a different ending `.log` exists in that directory.

What I got so far is this:

```
find . -name "*.ft1" -exec grep -l "special" {} \; -execdir ls *log \;
```

However, this gives me an error each time the `ls` is executed:

```
ls: cannot access *log: No such file or directory
```

But I *know* that there are such files in that directory. I also tried escaping the star, so the expression becomes `-execdir ls \*log \;`, but the error persists.

I also had a look at [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/185227/using-find-to-list-all-files-under-certain-directory) similar question, but I cannot currently see how that helps me with my problem.

How do I get this to behave correctly? Bonus points for a solution that only lists `.log` files with the same name stem as the found `.ft1` files.

Comment: Why not `find -name "*special*.ft1` rather than `find | grep`?

Comment: `special` is part of the file contents, not the name.

Comment: Does `.log` file also contain `special` string ? Or you're trying to do something like this `if (myFile.ft1 exists) ; if (has "special");then  check  whether myFile.log exists`    ?

Comment: Horrible pseudo code, i know . . .but hopefully it makes sense

Comment: @Serg Heh, what a simple solution to my problem. In this case, the `.log` also contains the `special` string. But the general solution by @DopeGhoti works for more use-cases.

Comment: Alright. Dont forget to mark @DopeGhoti answer as accepted if that solves your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is that you need a shell to interpret the `*.log` glob. So you need `-execdir` to invoke a shell. The following snippet will also address your "same name stem" requirement

```
find . -name "*.ft1" -exec grep -l "special" {} \; \
-execdir bash -c 'x=$1; x=${x%.txt}; ls "$x".log' bash {} \;
```

Comment: You could simply run `... \; -exec sh -c 'ls "${0%.ft1}.log" 2>/dev/null' {} \;`

Answer (score 4):

Assuming no spaces in your file names (and that your heart isn't set on using `find`), this should do the trick:

```
for file in *.ft1; do
   if grep -q 'special' ${file}; then
      ls -l ${file%.ft1}.log 2> /dev/null
   fi
done
```

It uses bash string manipulation to pull `.ft1` off of the end.  I could use `${file/ft1/log}`, but that would also match any filenames that happen to have `ft1` before the extension.

I redirect `stderr` from `ls` to hide attempts to `ls` the `.log` files that do not exist.

Comment: I use `find` because there are many occurrences of `.ft1` files at different depths in the tree. I guess you could do something like `for file in $(find . -name "*.ft1"); do` ?

Comment: You absolutely could.  I just tested that, and it works identically, with the added bonus of recursive directory tree walking.

Comment: Sweet, that did the trick. I'll mark your answer accepted if no `find`-only solution comes along in the next couple of days. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to have helped!

Comment: It'd be better to do `find . -name \*.ft1 | while read -r file; do` rather than the `for` loop, just to handle nonstandard filenames (and to not read the whole `find` output into memory, if it's large).

Comment: What is the logic of not quoting your vars and then saying _"Assuming no spaces in your file names"_ ?

Comment: @don_crissti - i bit my tongue, but ive come back to it, head sideways, like three times now.

Answer (score 3):

A very crude solution with `find` , `awk`, and `bash`. Basic idea, find all files with `ft1` extension, give them as list of command line args to `grep`, which outputs a list of files with do contain "special" string, then pipe that output to `awk` that will string out `ft1` extension and replace it with "log" extension.  Finally give it to bash, which will check if a log file with same extension exists

```
find . -type f -iname "*.ft1"  -exec grep "special" {} + | awk -F':' '{gsub(/\.ft1/,"");print $1".log"}'  | xargs -I {} bash -c " [ -f {}  ] && echo {} exists"
```

Small demo

```
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir2$ ls
one.ft1  one.log  three.ft1  two.ft1  two.log
xieerqi@eagle:~/testdir2$ find . -type f -iname "*.ft1"  -exec grep "special" {} + | awk -F':' '{gsub(/\.ft1/,"");print $1".log"}'  | xargs -I {} bash -c " [ -f {}  ] && echo {} exists"
./two.log exists
./one.log exists
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `grep -r` and `awk`

```
grep -rl 'special' *.ft1 | awk '{sub(/\.ft1$/,"");system("sh -c \"[ -f "$0".log ] && echo \\\"["$0".log\\\"] exists for ["$0".ft1]\"")}'
```

or with the output of `ls`

```
grep -rl 'special' *.ft1 | awk '{sub(/\.ft1$/,"");system("sh -c \"[ -f "$0".log ] && ls "$0".log \"")}'
```

---

*Example*

```
% grep -rl 'special' *.ft1 | awk '{sub(/\.ft1$/,"");system("sh -c \"[ -f "$0".log ] && echo \\\"["$0".log\\\"] exists for ["$0".ft1]\"")}'
[one.log] exists for [one.ft1]

% grep -rl 'special' *.ft1 | awk '{sub(/\.ft1$/,"");system("sh -c \"[ -f "$0".log ] && ls "$0".log \"")}'
one.log

% ls -laog                        
total 100
drwxrwx--x   4  4096 Nov 13 22:03 .
drwxr-xr-x 272 86016 Nov 13 22:03 ..
drwxrwxr-x   2  4096 Nov 13 20:37 bar
drwxrwxr-x   2  4096 Nov 13 20:37 foo
-rw-rw-r--   1     8 Nov 13 21:55 one.ft1
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Nov 13 21:54 one.log
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Nov 13 21:54 three.ft1
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Nov 13 21:54 two.ft1
-rw-rw-r--   1     0 Nov 13 21:54 two.log

% cat one.ft1
special

% cat two.ft1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `zsh` alternative:

```
print -rl -- **/*.ft1(.e_'grep -q special $REPLY && REPLY=$REPLY:r.log && [[ -f $REPLY ]]'_)
```

This will recursively search for `.ft1` files containing that string and print only the corresponding `.log` files. If you want to print all the `.ft1` files that contain the string `special` *and* the corresponding `.log` files (if any) then just replace `grep`'s `-q` with `-l`.
See [here how it works](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/225355) (this one has an additional condition - the `grep` part, the rest is the same).